# Easiest way to "goto source code" for Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As a Ruby/Rails non-pro, I often want to check out the code for a rails method to see how it's implemented...

For example, I was using "form_for", and I wanted to check out the code to see how it works. The slightly lame way I did this was to just google "rails form_for" which takes me to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html, where I can view the source for form_for.

How do rails/ruby pro's accomplish a similar task? Is there a simple way (without using IDEs) that you can quickly dig this out? Or is it a case of over time learning where stuff is located and find/grep-ing it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer http://railsapi.com/ both local and remote. Quick search, nice design and magic [Show on Github](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/48fbe7b0d8fcecce200ea35f46a8716077e13aea/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L261) link

Comment: Nice site. I think for pure ease this wins because it requires the smallest amount of brain effort :)

Comment: Seems to be down. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I clone the rails repository

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
```

after I grep on it

```
git grep 'form_for'
```

After my Vim editor help my with Ctags to navigate on source code.

If you want some example of code using you can see test unit.

Comment: you can also generate a tag file from your gems. I use rtags and this bash command to index the gems of my Gemfile + the current project + rails: rtags --vi -R . `ruby -e 'dirs=%x(gem dependency rails).map{|l| %x(gem which #{$1}) if l.match(/^\s+(\w+)/)}; dirs+= %x(rake gems).map{|l| %x(gem which #{$2}) if l.match(/\[(I|F|R)\] (\w+)/)}; puts dirs.uniq.compact.map{|d| File.dirname d}.join(" ")'`

Comment: arg comments have screwed the command, the grey area should be surrounded by back ticks

Comment: Didn't know about "git grep", that's pretty useful :)